# I Want to show video in high quality in my wordpress slider

Tags: wordpress

I have a video in my slider in this video it starts with low quality and after 2 seconds it shows high quality.
I want to start my video in high quality from start in slider.
my video came from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

for youtube video in wordpress you can use plugin slider-video
https://wordpress.org/plugins/slider-video/ here easly manage youtube video with slider